# Push multiple branches with --atomic using GitPython

Tags: python, git, atomic, gitpython

I am trying to use the `--atomic` feature introduced in git 2.4, which allows you to push multiple branches in one command atomically.   I can run this command successfully from the command line:
`git push --atomic origin branch1 branch2 branch3`

However I have been unable to get this to work through GitPython using `Repo.git.push("--atomic", "origin", "branch1 branch2 branch3")`.

In the error that follows I can see that the command sent to command line by GitPython is:
`git push --atomic origin branch1 branch2 branch3`
Which is exactly what works successfully from the command line.

Has anyone been able to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written this, you're passing the branches as a single argument with spaces in it.  The shell equivalent to this is as follows:

```
git push --atomic origin 'branch1 branch2 branch3'
```

Git doesn't like this because you're telling it you want to push a single branch with spaces in it and spaces are not allowed in branch names.  You instead want to write your command with multiple arguments:

```
Repo.git.push("--atomic", "origin", "branch1", "branch2", "branch3")
```

Comment: Works perfectly and makes sense, thank you.
One question of clarification though,  from the error output:
```cmdline: git push --atomic origin automationTestBranch1 automationTestBranch2```
the command that it claims it sent to the command line looks the same as what I successfully run from the command line (and I dont see an enclosing pair or "'" around the branch names.   Is git really being sent that command via the command line, or is this just a representation of a different api that GitPython has with git for issuing commands?